# If $[G:N]$ and $|H|$ are relatively primes, then $H\lt N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to show that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:N]$ and $|H|$ are relatively primes, then $H\lt N$. I've already found $|H|||N|$ but I couldn't go further, I need help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a bit more detail on what you have tried/where you got stuck. Without that, it is hard to help out (without doing the whole problem, at least; and that won't really help you over your bump).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the subgroup $HN$ of $G$ and note that $(HN)/N \cong H/(H\cap N)$.

Comment: I know that, but I couldn't move foward

Comment: @user75086: Staring from my hint, you will know that $[H: H\cap N]=[(HN):N]\mid [G:N]$. Can you see how to deduce the conclusion now?

Comment: In other words, consider the order of $H/(H\cap N)$ in two ways: first, as a divisor of $|H|$, and second, as a divisor of $|G/N|$. Given the size of $H/(H\cap N)$, what does that tell us about $H\cap N$ in relation to $H$?

Comment: yes, I found $H\subset N$, but I couldn't find $H\lt N$

Comment: @anon: Did you talk to the OP? Then you should @him/her.

Comment: @user75086: What do you mean? You know that $H$ is a subset of $N$ and and you also know that both $H$ and $N$ are subgroups of $G$, so of course $H$ is a subgroup of $N$, i.e. $H< N$.

Comment: @Landscape Yes, of course, you're right. thank you for helping me.

Comment: @user75086: You are welcome.

Comment: @user75086: I just viewed your profile page and saw that I had answered your question here. Just in case, do you know how to accept an answer? You may refer to [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3287/46120).

Comment: sorry, my fault!

Comment: @user75086: Please never mind. It seems a common phenomenon that new users in this website may not notice to accept answers. Thank you for accepting my answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

The image of $H$ under the canonical projection $G\to G/N$ is a subgroup of order dividing both $|H|$ and $|G/N|=[G:N]$, hence is trivial, hence is contained in the kernel $N$.